# TinyMCE file manager object not found in laravel application

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I just install `UniSharp/laravel-filemanager` but there's an issue with the file manager.

I am using editor on admin area so my routes are protected

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'preventBackHistory']], function () {

    Route::resource('/private-job', 'PrivateJob\privateJobController');

    Route::resource('/newspaper', 'newspaper\newspaperController');

    Route::resource('/scholarships', 'scholarship\ScholarshipController');

    Route::resource('/foreign-jobs', 'AbroadJons\AbroadJobsController');


    Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function () {

        Route::get('/items', 'ItemsController@index');
        Route::post('/items/{result}', 'ItemsController@AddItems');
        Route::post('/delete-items/{id}', 'ItemsController@DeleteItem');
        Route::resource('/create-users', 'ACLEntrust\RegisterController');
        Route::resource('/role', 'ACLEntrust\RoleController');
    });

});
```

when i use this route demo works fine but when i use the editor in my custom form it shows object not found when i browse for image uploading :

```
http:localhost/abc/laravel-filemanager/demo
```

Custom textarea:

Job Description

```
                <textarea name="job_desc" class="form-control my-editor">{!! `old('job_desc') !!}</textarea>`
            </div>
            <script>
                var editor_config = {
                    path_absolute: "/",
                    selector: "textarea.my-editor",
                    plugins: [
                        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
                        "link image"
                    ],
                    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
                    relative_urls: false,
                    file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
                        var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
                        var y = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

                        var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
                        if (type == 'image') {
                            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
                        } else {
                            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
                        }

                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                            file: cmsURL,
                            title: 'Filemanager',
                            width: x * 0.8,
                            height: y * 0.8,
                            resizable: "yes",
                            close_previous: "no"
                        });
                    }
                };

                tinymce.init(editor_config);
            </script>
            <script>
```

Commands used to install package

```
composer require unisharp/laravel-filemanager:~1.8
```

Edit `config/app.php`

```
Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
 Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,

'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public

 php artisan route:clear
 php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Well how are you including TinyMCE? We see the call, but we have no idea how you bring the package in.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i just updated my questions you can read now